# Backward compatibility with Modernize (Python2 to Python3) fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, migration

I have a simple sample script written in python2. Since we are migrating to python3, I am trying to get familiar with the tools that ae present. The modernize tool, helps me to achieve a python3 code. I run it, I get the result expected.

However, modernize promises backward compatibility, I expect the newly generated code to run in python2 as well.

While running with python2 Interpreter, I face issues as shown below:

Eg:
Sample.py

```
import Queue
from urllib2 import urlopen

def greet(name):
    print 'Hello',
    print name

print "What's your name?",
name = raw_input()
greet(name)
```

From the directory on the commandline

```
python-modernize -w Sample.py
```

New Sample.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import six.moves.queue
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
from six.moves import input

def greet(name):
    print('Hello', end=' ')
    print(name)

print("What's your name?", end=' ')
name = input()
greet(name)
```

I run the new script from the command line. Produces correct results.

```
py Sample.py
```

However, since it is backward compatible, when I do the following I get errors:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe Sample.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sample.py", line 3, in <module>
    import six.moves.queue
ImportError: No module named six.moves.queue
```

Should the new script be modified again? Is modernize not fully backward compatible?
Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the `six` module ?

`pip install six`

https://pypi.org/project/six/

Comment: yes, six is installed

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is on the same regard as pip installing libraries in different versions. I was installing the library in python3. So now I managed to get it done on python2. [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71206726/installing-same-packages-for-different-python-versions-on-windows10)

[PythonDocumentation](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html?highlight=pip)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).