# Installing same packages for different python versions on Windows10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, package

I have two versions of python installed on my system. (python 2.7 and python 3.9.6)
Task is to migrate python2.7 to python3.9

Because of the environmental variable order, my call to `python --version` leads to 3.9.6.

I have installed `modernize`, `six` and `future` libraries using `pip install`.

So I think, they have been installed under python3.9.6

However, since I am using `modernize`,`six` and `future`, I would want to check the backward compatibility of these libraries.
While doing so, ie: While running the code with the python2 interpreter, I get issue as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from six.moves import input
ImportError: No module named six.moves
```

Could anyone guide me as to how to install the library for python2 specifically?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the issue was with the pip installations. Since I had two different versions of python, the path was set in a way that Python3 was of priority. So, on some googling, I figured we can install the library to a specific version using the link here: [with multiple versions](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html?highlight=pip)
[image]